# Regex for Proxy Server to add edufilter to youtube requests

Tags: regex, firewall

I am working on Internet filtering. This is a somewhat proprietary system I suppose (Comsifter), but it is based on Dan's Guardian, so hopefully there will be a few people around here that can benefit from the answer to my question.

I am pretty sure the regex URL modify rules I want to use should be similar to these. The formatting might be different from other programs, but I think it makes sense what it is doing. It finds the left, and replaces with the right with a redirect I believe.

```
"https://www(\.google\..*)"->"https://nosslsearch\1"
"(http://[^/]*www\.google\..*\?.*)"->"\1&safe=vss"
"(http://[^/]*bing\..*\?.*)"->"\1&adlt=strict"
"(http://[^/]*yahoo\..*\?.*)"->"\1&vm=r"
"(http://[^/]*youtube\..*\?.*$)"->"\1&edufilter=wQL9mInebtaQ3b9HtRAOIA"
"(http://[^/]*youtube\.[^?]*$)"->"http://youtube.com/?edufilter=wQL9mInebtaQ3b9HtRAOIA"
"https://[^/]*youtube\..*"->"http://youtube.com/education"
```

however, I can't quite get the youtube ones to work, but I think the rest are good now. I get a redirect loop on youtube pages, or a time out, or something like that depending what I try for my incoming URL. I also tried this code:

```
"(^http://[^/]*youtube\..*\?.*$)"->"\1&edufilter=wQL9mInebtaQ3b9HtRAOIA"
"(^http://[^/]*youtube\.[^?]*$)"->"\1?edufilter=wQL9mInebtaQ3b9HtRAOIA"
"^https://[^/]*youtube\..*"->"http://youtube.com"
```

which seemed to work sometimes, but wasn't not quite right either.
I bet if I had a negation of the edufilter in the first line it might help, but I can't figure out how to do that.
Any help on these rules, or better ones, more effecient ones, etc. would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is at least a partial answer. I just need to figure out my HTTPS line now.

From http://linuxcentre.net/wiki/index.php/Web_Content_Filtering:

```
# Youtube (use our unique Youtube for schools code)
# remove any existing edufilter param
"(^http://[^/]*\.youtube\.[^?]*\?)(.+&)?(edufilter=[^&]*)"->"\1\2"
# add in our edufilter param
"(^http://[^/]*\.youtube\.[^?]*\?)"->"\1edufilter=YOUR CODE HERE&"
# or if no params add ours in
"(^http://[^/]*\.youtube\.[^?]*$)"->"\1/?edufilter=YOUR CODE HERE"
```

Seems to work great on the HTTP requests.

Comment: My understanding is now that it just isn't possible to filter in https the same way, and I just ended up blocking youtube https somewhere else in the config. I don't remember where actually.

Comment: Once I put the content filter in proxy mode, I was able to. The line for https was something like "^https(://www.youtube.*)"->"http\1" and I put that before the other youtube lines.